# Sbt compile error with poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9.jar using Scala

Tags: java, scala, apache-poi, sbt, scala-2.10

I'm trying to compile my project with SBT, but I get this error and can not figure out why:

```
YoBre$ sbt compile
[info] Loading project definition from /opt/virtualenvs/venv1/scala/name/project
[info] Set current project to name (in build file:/opt/virtualenvs/venv1/scala/name/)
[info] Compiling 4 Scala sources and 5 Java sources to /opt/virtualenvs/venv1/scala/name/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[error] error while loading CTP, class file '/opt/virtualenvs/venv1/scala/name/lib_managed/jars/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9.jar(org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/CTP.class)' is broken
[error] (class java.lang.NullPointerException/null)
[error] error while loading CTTbl, class file '/opt/virtualenvs/venv1/scala/name/lib_managed/jars/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9.jar(org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/CTTbl.class)' is broken
[error] (class java.lang.NullPointerException/null)
[error] error while loading CTTc, class file '/opt/virtualenvs/venv1/scala/name/lib_managed/jars/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9.jar(org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/CTTc.class)' is broken
[error] (class java.lang.NullPointerException/null)
[error] three errors found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 6 s, completed 18-set-2013 12.31.36
```

This project contains code Java and Scala. The error occurred when I translated into Scala a feature related to the splitting of the word documents that was previously written in java. The error is in fact tied to a jar file library org.apache.poi.

I tried to document but I have not found similar cases.

Any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried adding the jar file as an external dependency? In your build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.poi" % "poi-ooxml-schemas" % "3.9"
```

Answer (score 1):

I've updated the version of POI to 3.10-beta2.
However, there was no dependence `"org.apache.poi"% "-OOXML schemas"% "1.0"`

After adding it all works properly

thank you all for the answers!

```
  lazy val poiVersion = "3.10-beta2"
  lazy val libPoi ="org.apache.poi" % "poi" % poiVersion
  lazy val libPoiScratchpad ="org.apache.poi" % "poi-scratchpad" % poiVersion
  lazy val libPoiOOXML ="org.apache.poi" % "poi-ooxml" % poiVersion
  lazy val libPoiOOXMLSchema= "org.apache.poi" % "ooxml-schemas" % "1.0"
  lazy val libPoiComponents = Seq(libPoi, libPoiScratchpad, libPoiOOXML, libPoiOOXMLSchema)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856266/class-broken-error-with-joda-time-using-scala), and I suspect you may have the same issue.  Scala cannot load classes with missing annotations, so perhaps there is a missing dependency that is otherwise optional for Java.

Check your dependency list by executing `show compile:dependency-classpath` in sbt and make sure that you have all of the prerequisites listed at the [Apache POI Project site](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html).