# How is ScalaRunTime.stringOf(x) not failing when x.toString fails?

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

Whilst trying to figure out some `joda-time` `DateTime` (timestamp formatting) issues I opened a REPL with

```
scala -cp joda-time-2.3.jar
```

and forgot to add the `joda-convert` jar, and eventually got a

```
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: org.joda.convert.ToString
```

([The entire stacktrace](https://gist.github.com/dwijnand/c70e893806fee7b37871))

I was able to simplify this to:

```
> scala -cp joda-time-2.3.jar
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.0 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_05).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val dt = new org.joda.time.DateTime
warning: Class org.joda.convert.FromString not found - continuing with a stub.
warning: Class org.joda.convert.ToString not found - continuing with a stub.
warning: Class org.joda.convert.FromString not found - continuing with a stub.
warning: Class org.joda.convert.ToString not found - continuing with a stub.
dt: org.joda.time.DateTime = 2014-05-14T17:54:24.511+01:00

scala> scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime.stringOf(dt)
res0: String = 2014-05-14T17:54:24.511+01:00

scala> dt.toString
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: org.joda.convert.ToString
```

How is `ScalaRunTime.stringOf(dt)` succeeding where `dt.toString` fails?

Comment: Also, previously http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856266/class-broken-error-with-joda-time-using-scala

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You didn't post the stack trace, which is a compiler crash and not a failed assertion by joda.

The REPL is crashing compiling the expression.

It looks like `AbstractDateTime` has an overloaded `toString` method, and overload resolution crashes on the `@ToString` annotation on the usual `toString()`. (The symbol for `ToString` is missing.)

But `stringOf(x: Any)` is just invoking `Object.toString()`, of course.

There are [some known issues](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7751), apparently.  A [recent issue](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8442) was fixed.

On 2.10.4:

```
scala> (dt: Any).toString
res0: String = 2014-05-14T11:56:21.794-07:00

scala> dt.toString
<console>:9: error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method toString in class AbstractDateTime of type (x$1: String, x$2: java.util.Locale)String
and  method toString in class AbstractDateTime of type (x$1: String)String
match expected type ?
              dt.toString
                 ^

scala> dt.toString()  // crashes
```

2.10.3 is bumpier and claims `error while loading DateTime, class file is broken`.

The crash is on 2.11.0.

Comment: added a link to the stacktrace

Comment: Ah, yeah I _don't_ get an error when running `(dt: Any).toString`. It's mental that that & `dt.toString` does two different things, unless I'm missing something.. Thanks for the answer.