# Why is x.toString different from (x: Any).toString

Tags: scala, inheritance, overloading, read-eval-print-loop

Following on from [How is ScalaRunTime.stringOf(x) not failing when x.toString fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23660990/463761), how is

```
x.toString
```

different from

```
(x: Any).toString
```

Also, how about

```
"" + x
```

Example REPL session:

```
> scala -cp joda-time-2.3.jar
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.0 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_05).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val dt = new org.joda.time.DateTime
warning: Class org.joda.convert.FromString not found - continuing with a stub.
warning: Class org.joda.convert.ToString not found - continuing with a stub.
warning: Class org.joda.convert.FromString not found - continuing with a stub.
warning: Class org.joda.convert.ToString not found - continuing with a stub.
dt: org.joda.time.DateTime = 2014-05-15T09:27:17.929+01:00

scala> (dt: Any).toString
res0: String = 2014-05-15T09:27:17.929+01:00

scala> "" + dt
res1: String = 2014-05-15T09:27:17.929+01:00

scala> dt.toString
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: org.joda.convert.ToString
at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1410)
at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$TypeSymbol.isNonBottomSubClass(Symbols.scala:3040)
at scala.reflect.internal.AnnotationInfos$AnnotationInfo.matches(AnnotationInfos.scala:305)
at scala.reflect.internal.AnnotationInfos$Annotatable$class.dropOtherAnnotations(AnnotationInfos.scala:68)
at scala.reflect.internal.AnnotationInfos$Annotatable$class.hasAnnotation(AnnotationInfos.scala:53)
at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.hasAnnotation(Symbols.scala:174)
at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$class.improves$1(Infer.scala:61)
at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$$anonfun$4.apply(Infer.scala:65)
at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Infer$$anonfun$4.apply(Infer.scala:65)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer to your other question clearly describes the problem, I'll give it another shot and describe in more detail what is going on.

When you call `dt.toString` you actually call the `toString` method of the `DateTime` class, which also contains an overloaded version of this method. This leads to a compilation error, not a runtime error, what actually is a bug in the compiler (but it seems to be fixed in a more recent Scala version as the other answer mentions)

In the case of `(dt: Any).toString` or `"" + dt` you are not directly calling one of the overloaded `toString` methods in `DateTime` but the one defined in `Any` (which is in fact `java.lang.Object#toString`). The compiler doesn't even see the overloaded `toString` method of the `DateTime` subclass - hence the corresponding bug doesn't make any problems.

At runtime, because of dynamic dispatch not the implementation of `Any.toString` is called but `DateTime.toString`. This dispatch is not done by scalac at compile time but by the JVM at runtime. The latter doesn't have the overloading bug - hence no error occurs.

Comment: Ah, the distinction of compilation & runtime. I understand. Thanks.