# Play Framework 2.3 MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework-2.3

I'm trying to develop a little web app with the play framework 2.3 in scala. For this application I need access to a MongoDB instance. For now I could configure my build to download the dependencies for morphia. This is the entry in dependencies for morphia:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.google.code.maven-play-plugin.org.playframework.modules.morphia" % "play-morphia" % "1.2.12"
```

During compilation the play compiler complains about a missing class `play.db.Model`. The exact error messages are these:

```
Error:Play 2 Compiler:  Class play.db.Model not found - continuing with a stub.
Error:Play 2 Compiler:                                              ^
Warning:Play 2 Compiler:  Class play.db.Model not found - continuing with a stub.
Warning:Play 2 Compiler:  Class play.data.binding.ParamNode not found - continuing with a stub.
Warning:Play 2 Compiler:  Class play.mvc.Scope not found - continuing with a stub.
Warning:Play 2 Compiler:  9 warnings found
```

Am I missing some dependency or configuration?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you will need to add other dependencies to your sbt config file; see this question for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856266/class-broken-error-with-joda-time-using-scala

Comment: Mhh... Any idea what libraries are missing?

Comment: Morphia plugin is not actively maintained. It wont work for play-2.3 but even if it did... Should not use an unmaintained project. I think you should use one of - Casbah or ReactiveMongo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this in build.sbt

> "org.mongodb.morphia" % "morphia" % "0.109"

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use a library that was written for Play 1.x.

There is, however, [a new plugin for Play version 2](https://github.com/leodagdag/play2-morphia-plugin)

Look at [this link](https://github.com/leodagdag/play2-morphia-plugin/issues/20) for more on how to use it.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't bring me any further since all repositories mentioned in the second link seem to be down. And I don't really want to start building dependencies on my own. But thanks anyway.