# Class java.time.Duration not found - continuing with a stub

Tags: scala, sbt

Given:

```
$cat build.sbt 
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= List(
  "io.spray"          %% "spray-client"        % "1.3.3"
  ,"io.spray"          %%  "spray-json"         % "1.3.2"
  ,"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor"          % "2.4.2"
  ,"com.typesafe"      % "config" % "1.3.0"
  ,"org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.6" % "test"
)
```

Using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7705091/409976), I attempted to use JDK 7.

However, I got the following errors:

```
$sbt -java-home /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/ clean test
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/Kevin/Workspace/Work/project/project
[info] Set current project to project (in build file:/Users/Kevin/Workspace/Work/project/)
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Mar 14, 2016 3:51:10 PM
[info] Updating {file:/Users/Kevin/Workspace/Work/project/}project...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 9 Scala sources to /Users/Kevin/Workspace/Work/project/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] Class java.time.Duration not found - continuing with a stub.
[error] Class java.time.Duration not found - continuing with a stub.
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 5 s, completed Mar 14, 2016 3:51:16 PM
```

Looking at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13856382/409976), I'm guessing/speculating that I need to add a java8 time library as a dependency?

Comment: So does that mean that one of my dependencies' is using JDK8's `java.time.Duration`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Akka 2.4 requires JDK8 unless you are using a commercial build, this is mentionned in the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.2/intro/getting-started.html#Prerequisites).

relevant extract

> Akka requires that you have Java 8 or later installed on your machine.
>
> Typesafe provides a commercial build of Akka and related projects such as Scala or Play as part of the Reactive Platform which is made available for Java 6 in case your project can not upgrade to Java 8 just yet. It also includes additional commercial features or libraries.

Typesafe config 1.3.0 also [depends on java8](https://github.com/typesafehub/config#binary-releases)

> Version 1.2.1 and earlier were built for Java 6, while newer versions (1.3.0 and above) will be built for Java 8.

Also beware that spray-client 1.3.3 depends on Akka 2.3.9 (see http://spray.io/project-info/current-versions/#current-versions)
you may want to upgrade to [akka-http](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.2/scala/http/client-side/index.html) which is the successor to spray.

(since you seem to use a posix compliant system, you may want to have a look at [jenv](https://github.com/gcuisinier/jenv) for managing per project jdk versions)

Comment: I downgraded from Akka v. `2.4.2` to `2.3.14`, per `Akka 2.3.14 (previous stable release) for Scala 2.10 / 2.11 and Java 6+` in the [docs](http://akka.io/docs/). But, when re-running the same `sbt -java-home .../jdk7/...`, I got the same error.

Comment: check your typesafe config version, downgrading both akka and typesafe config, the warning disappears.

Comment: Thanks, Jean, downgrading to `"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor"          % "2.3.14"` and `"com.typesafe"      % "config" % "1.2.1"` worked for JDK7. How'd you know to change the `typesafe config` too?

Comment: Well through technical watch I know lightbend/typesafe has been migrating its OSS libraries to support java 8 (for performance with the lambda bytecode emitter and for business by providing java 6 compatible builds to paying customers). I copied the akka hello-world sample and tried to compile them with your build definition. After downgrading akka I noticed I was still getting the warning and checked the `config` documentation :)

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not sure how to fix this error.

This error indicates that somewhere in your code you're relaying on `java.time.Duration` which is a new API exposed in Java 8. Since you've downgraded to Java 7, this class is no longer available.

Either remove the dependency, or revert back to Java8.

Comment: how can I track that dependency?

Comment: @Kevin you can use [sbt-dependency-graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) to find out your dependency chain

Comment: This specific class is available as a backport for JDK 6/7
https://github.com/ThreeTen/threetenbp

Comment: Thanks - that's a useful plugin. I did see `[info]   | +-org.scala-lang.modules:scala-java8-compat_2.11:0.7.0` under the Akka v. `2.4.2`. Then, after using v. `2.3.14`, I no longer see a `jdk8` dependency via `sbt dependencyTree`, but I see the same error when re-running `sbt -java-home ...`

Comment: @Kevin Did you reload sbt?