# sbt - joda convert not found

Tags: scala, sbt, jodatime

I'm getting this error:

```
[warn] Class org.joda.convert.FromString not found - continuing with a stub.
```

But in build.sbt it's explicitly included:

```
libraryDependencies += "joda-time" %  "joda-time" % "2.9.6"
libraryDependencies += "org.joda" % "joda-convert" % "1.8.1"
```

and that seems to be the fix for most people having this issue, eg. [Class broken error with Joda Time using Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856266/class-broken-error-with-joda-time-using-scala) .
Running dependency graph I see evictions:

```
[info]       +-joda-time:joda-time:2.3 (evicted by: 2.9.6)
[info]       +-joda-time:joda-time:2.8.2 (evicted by: 2.9.6)
[info]       +-joda-time:joda-time:2.9.6
[info]       +-org.joda:joda-convert:1.8.1
[info]       +-org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.11:1.0.5 [S]
[info]
[success] Total time: 10 s, completed May 11, 2017 6:38:09 PM
```

but it seems that in the end the latest versions win and looks like convert is included. Tests run fine and date conversions as well.

Right now, I'm at a bit of a loss.. How should I fix this / debug this in sbt?

Comment: can you downgrade the joda time version to 2.1 as 
`libraryDependencies += "joda-time" %  "joda-time" % "2.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.joda" % "joda-convert" % "1.8.1"`

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Unfortunately it didn't work either..

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Well, no, it's still being overridden to 2.9.6 due to com.typesafe.play:play-json_2.11:2.6.0-M6. Gonna try a dependency override next

Comment: 1) You already have joda from transitive dependencies so it could be used. The problem is 2 different potentially incompatible versions remains. 2) Exclude transitive dependencies. But this is some kind of mine bomb within libraries.  3) If it's possible use java 8 time package (imho the best way).

Comment: Yeah, it's still not working, even forcing a dependency override for both joda and convert. I'll try the exclude transitive dependencies now.. @Zernike At this point, it's not really possible to replace joda in all project modules now.

Comment: Yet another sad approach exists (I hate it because situation becomes worse). Separate code parts with joda deps as standalone modules and then shade joda in packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, in my case it was simply a matter of excluding the transitive dependency. Something like this:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.com" %% "core" % "0.1-SNAPSHOT" exclude("org.joda", "joda-convert")
```